# Automatically rendering jade file as if it was an html file?

Tags: node.js, pug

I can't find an answer to this, despite it seeming rather useful.

I would like to host a site using node.js to serve compiled jade files instead of html files. Currently, I'm using:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});
```

How can I get it to find `page.jade` when someone types in `domain.com/page`? And furthermore, could I write links that way in the jade file (so `a(href='page') link` would link to the aforementioned page)?

Comment: what you want jade to do is what jade was made for. You need to set your view engine as jade and then do a res.render() on your jade files.

Comment: I set it up as such, `app.set('views', __dirname+ '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render(__dirname+'/');
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});` There is a file called `views/page1.jade`, however, upon `domain:port/page1` I get `cannot GET /page1`

Comment: set your path as `app.get('/:pageName')`... then `res.render(req.params.pageName+'.jade')`... req.params will contain the last part in property name pageName

Comment: That's perfect! I didn't know about the parameters and that together solved it.

Comment: @MukeshSoni, could you post your comment as an answer? It's actually the answer to the question, and it is very useful

Answer (score 1):

Set your path as

```
app.get('/:pageName')
// more code 
// then
res.render(req.params.pageName+'.jade')
```

`req.params` will contain the last part in property name `pageName`

Answer (score 0):

Express has a number of possible options for what it calls a "view engine".  In order to have it process jade files and serve them as html you must configure it to do so.

One of the easiest ways to do this, if you are starting fresh, is to simply create your project using the `express` command as [mentioned in their guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html).  The default views engine is jade and the following command sets stylus as the css processor:

```
express --css stylus myapp
```

If, instead, you are configuring your own server you need to configure the views engine:

```
app.configure(function(){

  app.set('views', path.join(staticDir,'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  ... the rest of your setup ...
}
```